# XLConnect function is not passing argument to system.file

Tags: r, validation, xlconnect

I have an issue with XLConnect library. Its system.file function, I've only seen be used with

```
file1 <- system.file(file, package ="XLConnect")
```

Where file is always equal to a string. However I have a list of strings with the file name of each file in it. I have this inside of a for loop that iterates through the list. For whatever reason, file1 is empty even though the file object has the equivalent "soandso.xlsx".

So my question is do I need file to be a string?

Edit #1: 
So I switched from using the XLConnect library which was giving me a separate error to xlsx library and at least now, I can get the code to run, albeit with different errors.

I think I am making progress though because I had the code unsuccessfully run past the first loop (since k incremented to 2) and I had something populate my dataset variable (where I store the 'read.xlsx2' reponse).

I've attached screenshot of my current error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

[image: Screenshot of my R Studio]

Edit # 2:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9413oee146v497/Q1%2C%202011%20-%20Halton%2C%20all%20home%20types.xlsx?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgaup2ihnlq7br2/Q4%2C%202015%20-%20Halton%2C%20condo%20types.xlsx?dl=0

I've included 2/60 file I need to attach. All files at my destination are Excel files, which are 10 columns wide and variable row length - due to new regions or just regions just being renamed. The new error I'm getting is :

In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file

Edit#3:

> source('~/.active-rstudio-document', echo=TRUE)

```
> library("openxlsx")

> file_list = list.files(pattern = "xlsx$")

> dataset = data.frame()

> for (file in file_list){
+ 
+   print(file)
+   temp = read.xlsx(file,sheet = 1, colNames = F)
+   temp$quarter = substr(file,1,2)
+   temp$year = s .... [TRUNCATED] 
[1] "~$Q1, 2011 - Halton, all home types.xlsx"
Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Sorry but I'm still having issues, however I know where the problem is. For some reason what's being printed as file is coming with "~$" before it, when I input just the file name 'Q1, 2011 - Halton, all home types.xlsx' as the file, it works and I get data to be inputted into dataframe. Now the problem with this I obviously cannot mass import 60 different Excel names...

Comment: If file is a list, and this line is inside a for loop (with index k) then try `file[[k]]`

Comment: I'm not sure if that cause the followup error but I took your advice and added a counter to my loop

Comment: Ditch my suggestion, the `file` variable in the for loop is a string and is correct.  But, is every file in the `file_list` and Excel file?

Comment: Yes all files in the destination are excel files (all xlsx files) - this seems like such an easy thing to do with r but i'm still having trouble with it.

Comment: I downloaded both files and the only problem I had was that these two files do not share the same column names, so a simple rbind() will not work. I  would also recommend to add year and quarter info as variables (columns) before joining all data together because the Excel tables do not contain this info.

Comment: Hey I figured out it was the format of file. Now I've already tried to add in the line of code `file=substring(file,3)` to remove the first two characters but for whatever reason, `[1] "Q1, 2011 - Halton, all home types.xlsx"
[1] ", 2011 - Halton, all home types.xlsx"` gets printed twice, which confuses me because I only have 1 file in the working directory. I'm trying to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `openxlsx` library and the following code:

```
library("openxlsx")

file_list = list.files(pattern = "xlsx$")

dataset = data.frame()

for (file in file_list){
    print(file)
    temp = read.xlsx(file,sheet = 1, colNames = F)
    temp$quarter = substr(file,1,2)
    temp$year = substr(file,4,8)
    dataset = rbind(dataset,temp)
}
```

**Edit 1:**
Added a print(file) to detect which xlsx file is having unzip problems.

**Edit 2:**
Added quarter and year information by reading them from the filename. This only works if all filenames follow the same pattern.

Comment: 'In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file' /error

I will further respond to your post in my original - for better formatting's sake

Comment: Yeah I had to edit the workbook through an excel macro just to make the data look prettier, but thanks for your help! What's weird is that I also had to add `for (file in file_list[-1])` to the for loop because the first entry into the list had that `~$` before it